# Probability to win this simple game?

Tags: probability

Let's play a game. 
You have a button to press.

On button click, you have n/10 chance of losing. n starts at 1 and is increased by 1 after each button click.

You win (if you didn't lose) after 3 clicks.

What are the probability of winning/losing ?

I'm not sure if the events are independent. Because the outcome of the first event will influence the rest of the game ? But on the other hand, at the 2nd round, we always have 
8/10 chance of not losing.

If they are in fact independent events, the chance of winning is 
${9}\over{10}$ $\cdot$  ${8}\over{10}$ $\cdot$ ${7}\over{10}$ 
which is roughly equal to $1/2$

What would be the probability of losing ?

Also, is this binomial ? I think it isn't because the probability changes each round.

I have some stat background but I'm kind of confused to apply it to a problem out of context.

This is not a homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability to win is $(1-\frac{1}{10})\cdot(1-\frac{2}{10})\cdot(1-\frac{3}{10})=0.504$.

The probability to lose is $1-0.504=0.496$.

---

An alternative way for calculating the probability to lose:

$\color{red}{\frac{1}{10}}+\color{green}{(1-\frac{1}{10})\cdot\frac{2}{10}}+\color{blue}{(1-\frac{1}{10})\cdot(1-\frac{2}{10})\cdot\frac{3}{10}}=0.496$.

Answer (score 0):

The events are not in fact independent, but that's not what matters. What matters is that for each even to happen the previous event HAD to happen with probability 1.

So if we are to "win" we have

(Probability of not losing on first press)x(Probability of not losing on second press | not lost on first press)x(Probability of not losing on third press | not lost on first or second press), which is indeed the answer given above.